# How to get elements above specific classes?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Sample content:

```
<div id="content">
    <h5>Title1</h5>
    <div class="text">text 1</div>

    <h5>Title2</h5>
    <h6>SubTitle</h6>
    <otherTag>bla bla</otherTag>
    <div class="text">text 2</div>

    <div class='pi'>post item</div>
    <div class="text">text 3</div>

    <div class="text">text 4</div>
</div>
```

Inside id `content`, I need to get class `text`, then get `<h5>`, `<h6>`, `<otherTag>`, `<div class='pi'>` which are belong to class `text`.

So my way is to get the class `text`, then get those things above it with `find_all_previous` until meet another class `text` or goes to the top id `content`. Problem is that `find_all_previous` returns all the previous contents. How can I make it stop searching at previous class `text` or at id `content`? And I don't think it's a good idea to use this method, since each searching returns all contents.

Using `find_previous` is not a good choice either, it has to detect elements one by one, and the elements is in no order, and some even absents.

```
html = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
content = html.find('div',{'id': 'content'})
paras = content.find_all('div', {'class': 'text'})

for para in paras:
    print(para.get_text())
    all_prevs = para.find_all_previous()
```

**Edited**

The result should grouped by class `text`, for example:

> Title2, SubTitle2, bla bla, Text2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, select all `.text` elements:

```py
text_elements = dom.select('.text')
```

Then use [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) on `.find_previous_siblings()` to only take until we encounter another `.text`:

```py
def is_not_text(element):
  return 'text' not in element.attrs.get('class', [])

other_elements = [
  [*takewhile(is_not_text, text.find_previous_siblings(True))]
  for text in text_elements
]

'''
[
  [<h5>Title1</h5>],
  [
    <othertag>bla bla</othertag>,
    <h6>SubTitle</h6>,
    <h5>Title2</h5>
  ],
  [<div class="pi">post item</div>],
  []
]
'''
```

You can also get the results as a dict if you so choose:

```py
other_elements = {
  text: [*takewhile(is_not_text, text.find_previous_siblings(True))]
  for text in text_elements
}

'''
{
  <div class="text">text 1</div>: [
    <h5>Title1</h5>
  ],
  <div class="text">text 2</div>: [
    <othertag>bla bla</othertag>,
    <h6>SubTitle</h6>,
    <h5>Title2</h5>
  ],
  <div class="text">text 3</div>: [
    <div class="pi">post item</div>
  ],
  <div class="text">text 4</div>: []
}
'''
```

Comment: I need to get the values with python ;-)

Comment: @jdleung I did include a Python snippet, didn't I? Edited to give it a more prominent place.

Comment: It does highlight the tags, but sorry, I'm not familiar with that way. Can I get values group by class `text`?

Comment: @jdleung Use `takewhile` then. See updated answer.

Comment: Great! It works but it misses `Title1` and `text 1`. I think the reason is that they are not between class `text`.  The last `text` is missed too.

Comment: @jdleung That means what you really want is every element that is not a `.text`, correct? Use `:not(.text)` then. Also, I'm pretty sure that my snippet outputs exactly what you specified in the question: You said you only want elements between `.text`, yet you are asking me to return the last `.text` as well; what *exactly* is the expected output?

Comment: I'm so sorry! It's my bad because I focused on the elements between tags so much, then gave a misleading question title and description. Actually what I want is that the class `text` and disorder. elements above them within id `content`.

Comment: I have modified the question title and description. My Apologies.

Comment: @jdleung It took me quite a while to deduce what the result you want is. Please specify only *the problem*, now how you want it to be solved (eventhough I eventually went in that way). See updated answer.

Comment: Well, it's a concise way to get the result! Although the results are separated in  text_elements and other_elements, but they can be iterated and combined with the same index. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jdleung Modifying the list comprehension so as to get a dict is easy enough: just add a key before the value and change square brackets to braces.

Comment: OK, I will take a try.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best solution to use `find_previous` one by one, but it gives me the values what I want. If you guys have better solution, please post it here.

```
def checkTop(prev):
    if prev.get('class') == ['text']:
        return True
    if prev.get('id') == 'content':
        return True
    return False

item_list = content.find_all('div', {'class': 'text'})

for item in item_list:
    prev = item.find_previous()
    if prev:    
        isTop = checkTop(prev)      
        while isTop == False:
            if prev.name == 'h6':
                subtitle = prev.get_text()
            if prev.name == 'h5':
                title  = prev.get_text()
            # and so on ...

            prev = prev.find_previous()
            isTop = checkTop(prev)  

    str = item.get_text()
```